# Como fazer condicao receber um parametro seguido de um argumento

Tags: linux, if, bash, shell, else

Venho tentando criar uma estrutura `if..else` com um parametro a passar. Veja:

## Exemplo

`$ opt-get -i pacote.tgz`

> Isso, estou criando algo similar a ferramenta **apt-get** do Sistema Operacional *Debian*.

Tenho feito a condicao para definir e verificar o parametro:

`if [ $1 = "-i" ]; then`

## Codigo

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# (c) 2016 - Diego Henrique Guilherme, <netcenter@globomail.com>
#
# Programa - opt-get
#
# Aponta para o repositorio
URL=http://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/slackware-8.1/slackware/tcl/

if [ $1="-i" -a $2="tgz" -o $2="gz" ]
then

     wget -c -qO- $URL$2 | sudo tar zxv -C /

else


     wget -c -P /tmp/ $URL$2

fi
```

## Comentario

Note que uso o parâmetro "-a"*(E)* para incluir mais de uma condição dentro da mesma função,

Nela os comandos são executados apenas caso a variável `"$1"` seja igual a `"-i"` E assim como o `"$2"` esta para `"tgz" e "gz"`.

Noutra possibilidade uso o "-o"*(OU)* para fazer com que o comando seja executado caso qualquer uma das condições extensao `"tgz", "gz"` seja verdadeira.

Como pode se ver criei *shell script* esteticamente parecido ao **apt-get** do *SO Debian*, tendo somente como tarefa principal baixar o pacote e instalar imediatamente caso o parametro "-i" for passado. Se nao for passado o parametro "-i", ele simplesmente baixa pacote na pasta `/tmp`, nao instala.

Ja estou ha um bom tempo alterando.. Nao sei onde posso estar errando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloco a disposição o *shell script* utilizando o conceito dos comandos de controle de fluxo, o `if`, que é baseado na lógica "se acontecer isso, irei fazer isso, se não, irei fazer aquilo". Veja:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# (c) 2016 - Diego Henrique Guilherme, <netcenter@globomail.com>
#
# Programa - opt-get
#

# Apontar para repositório
URL=http://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/slackware-8.1/slackware/tcl/

# Detectar Formato do pacote
EXT=$(echo $1 $2)

# Verificar extensão do pacote
if [ ${EXT##*.} != "tgz" ]
then
echo "Formato de pacote inválido. Verifique e tente novamente."

# Caso não seja passado parâmetro válido, descontinuar
elif [ $1 != "-i" -a $1 != "-d" ]
then

echo "Ops! opção inválida."

# Mostrar Auto-Ajuda caso nada seja argumentado
elif [ -z $1 ]
then

cat << "EOF"

Modo de Usar: opt-get [-id] <package.tgz>

Opções de Parâmetros válidos

-i  É um acrônimo da palavra - install
-d  É um acrônimo da palavra - download

NOTA! - Não será preciso colocar as duas opções ao mesmo tempo, 
uma vez que cada qual, tem por finalidade baixar o pacote.

A diferença fica por conta de "-i" baixar e auto-instalar
A opção "-d" somente baixa o pacote diretamente para /tmp

EOF

# Baixar e Instalar pacote 
elif [ $1 = "-i" ]
then

wget -c -qO- $URL$2 | sudo tar zxv -C /

# Somente Baixar o pacote
elif [ $1 = "-d" ]
then

wget -c -P /tmp $URL$2

fi
```

> Isso é algo relativamente simples, perto do propósito de um sistema de gerenciamento de pacotes que é uma coleção de ferramentas que fornece um método consistente de instalação, atualização e remoção de software em seu sistema. Entretanto, está feito!